# SQL field of date and want to save nothing to this field from a text box on winform

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have textboxes on a windows form.  For some of them there is no date that will initally be saved.  The SQL field binded to the text box is of type:  date.  When I go to save a new record, I get a System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException:

SqlDateTime overflow.  Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

How can I save this record, when I don't have a date to put in the date field yet?

This is the code I'm using

```
public static bool UpdateEngOrd(EngOrd oldEngOrd, EngOrd newEngOrd)
    {

        SqlConnection cnn = SqlDB.GetConnection();
        string strsql =
            "UPDATE EngOrd SET " +
            "filetype = @newfiletype, reqmeetdue = @newreqmeetdue " +               
            "WHERE eo = @oldeo";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newfiletype", newEngOrd.FileType);
        if (newEngOrd.ReqMeetDue == DateTime.MinValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newreqmeetdue", DBNull.Value);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newreqmeetdue", newEngOrd.ReqMeetDue);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldeo", oldEngOrd.EO);

        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (count > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the SQL field nullable? And how are you saving the data to the database? There's far too little information in this question.

Comment: the sql field is nullable

Comment: yes i am saving data to a sql database

Comment: I asked *how* you're saving the data. You've given us no code at all.

Comment: I put in the code above.  The field is newEngOrd.ReqMeetDue

Comment: Okay, so when it fails, which branch of the `if` statement is it taking?

Comment: I found the issue.  The syntax above works.  The problem was in the ADD part of the code (not posted).  I thought it was with the update portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you make this date field in sql table nullable ?

I am not sure, but this can be a problem in your case

You can use the following to make it nullable

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] INTEGER  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
   Dim _Date As SqlDateTime
   _Date = SqlDateTime.Null

   If (IsDBNull(Me.txtBox.Value)) Then
      _obj.Date= _Date
      Else
      _obj.Date=Convert.ToDateTime(txtBox.Value)
   End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it to a new DateTime, which defaults to DateTime.MinValue which is 1/1/0000. Try passing in DBNull instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The syntax above works. The problem was in the ADD part of the code (not posted). I thought it was with the update portion